# Find all pairs in an unsorted array whose sum is divisible by 4

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Find all pairs in an unsorted array whose sum is divisble by 4.
Kindly suggest an algorithm better than O(n*n)

```
e.g.

[1,2,4,0,20,22]
k=4
[0,4]
[0,20]
[20,4]
[2,22]
```

Comment: @user3676125 Can I use extra space?

Answer (score 8):

It can be done in `O(n+k)`, where `k` is the number of such pairs (which could be in `O(n^2)` itself).

The idea is to create 4 lists, `list0,list1,list2,list3`, where `list_i` holds all the elements `x` such that `x%4 ==i`.

Creating these lists is simple and is done in `O(n)`.

Once you have these lists, all you have to do is get all pairs where one element is from `list_i`, and other element is in `list_((4-i)%4)` (so list0+list0, list1+list3, list2+list2). This can be done very simply, and will generate all pairs pretty efficiently.

**Optimization note**: it can be done in-place (very little extra space) by "sorting" the array itself according to the modolus, so you will have the lists represented in the array itself.

---

**Example:** (from your list, with minimal modification)

```
array = [1,2,4,0,20,22,7]
```

Generate the lists:

```
list0 = [0,4,20]
list1 = [1]
list2 = [2,22]
list3 = [7]
```

Now,

```
"combine" list0 with itself: (0,4), (4,20), (0,20)
"combine" list2 with itself: (2,22)
"combine" list1 with list3: (1,7)
```

Comment: @gen-y-s That's depend on the distribution space you have for elements in the array. If `arr=[3,711,...,4k+3]` - `k` is actually 0 in this case. For uniformly distributed numbers - yes, `k` is in `O(n^2)` indeed.